# angularjs ng-model and ng-select strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of persons objects that I want to bind to a select element.

Controller implementation:

```
// Person controller
function PersonCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{id: 1, name: 'alex'}, {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}];
    $scope.selectedPerson = {id: 2, name: 'jhon'};  
}
```

Html markup:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-options="p.name for p in persons"></select>
```

The problem is that the binding seems to work only from the HTML to the scope and not the other way around. If I select an item from the drop down, it will correctly update the $scope.selectedPerson. But, if I initially set the value of the $scope.selectedPerson variable to one of the objects in the persons list, the value will not be reflected on the select control.

I also have fiddle that shows exactly what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/nE3gt/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the selectedPerson to an element in the persons array, not a new object - otherwise Angular has no idea they are the same thing.

```
// Person controller
function PersonCtrl($scope) {

$scope.persons = [{id: 1, name: 'alexx'}, {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}];

$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.persons[1];

$scope.submit = function () {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Person));
    $("#obj").text(JSON.stringify($scope.Person));
};
```

}

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nE3gt/2/

**edit**

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to do something along these lines:

```
// Person controller
function PersonCtrl($scope) {

    //serverData is the result of some http request...
    var serverData = {persons: [{id: 1, name: 'alexx'}, {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}], selectedPerson: {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}};

    $scope.persons = serverData.persons;
    $scope.selectedPerson = null;

    //find obj in persons that equals selectedPerson
    for(var i = 0, l = serverData.persons.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if(serverData.persons[i].id === serverData.selectedPerson.id)
        {
            $scope.selectedPerson = serverData.persons[i];
        }
    }

    $scope.submit = function () {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.Person));
        $("#obj").text(JSON.stringify($scope.Person));
    };
};
```

Even if your data comes back as different objects you need to make sure you're setting selectedPerson to an item that is in the persons array.

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nE3gt/4/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! The problem is that I am constructing a complex model on the server and this is where I set the selected object, along with populating the possible options. Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the data returned from the server is something like `{persons: [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}], selectedPerson: {id:2}}` ?

Comment: Yes, that is it. Can use something like ng-init here?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to the index of the array you're binding to:

```
$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.persons[0];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nE3gt/3/